# How to create unique constraints using hibernate for an existing table

Tags: hibernate

I have an existing table in database and I want to update that table by adding unique constraints to it.

I have updated my model class with appropriate annotations related to unique constraints.
Now, if I call `LocalSessionFactoryBean.updateDatabaseSchema()` method, then unique constraints are not created, but when I first drop the table and then call `LocalSessionFactoryBean.updateDatabaseSchema()` method then it creates the unique constraints in the table.

How can I create unique constraints to an existing table using hibernate without dropping the table?

Also let me know whether this is feasible in hibernate or not?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in hibernate?  Can't you just use native SQL in a script?

Comment: I am developing a product, which supports multiple databases. Native SQL is always an option at the end and for that I need to create multiple SQL queries for multiple databases. And I think, if hibernate can create unique constraints while creating tables then there should be a way to create unique constraints on existing tables also.

Comment: Hibernate won't be able to properly migrate the schema anyway if you have data inside, so you'll have to create a migration script anyway. Consider using Liquibase.